# Random access a value from Java HashMap, when using a custom class object as key for HashMap?

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I am using a custom class object as the key for a `HashMap`.  In this class definition, I have overridden the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.

```
public class TimeTableDataModel {

    Map <Course, List <Timings>> tm; 

    TimeTableDataModel() {
        tm = new HashMap<>();
    }

    void addCourseItem(Course course) {
        tm.put(course, new ArrayList<Timings>());
    }

    void addNewTimeTableItem(Course course, Timings newTiming) {
        List <Timings> t;
        if(!tm.containsKey(course)) {
            addCourseItem(course);
        }
        t = tm.get(course);
        t.add(newTiming);
        tm.put(course, t);
    }

    public static final class Course {
        private final String courseCode;
        private final String courseName;
        private final String section;
        private final String group;

        Course(String code, String courseName, String section, String group) {
            this.courseCode = code;
            this.courseName = courseName;
            this.section = section;
            this.group = group;
        }

        public String getCourseCode() { return courseCode; }
        public String getCourseName() { return courseName; }
        public String getSection() { return section; }
        public String getGroup() { return group; }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (!(obj instanceof Course)) {
                return false;
            }
            Course otherObj = (Course) obj;
            return Objects.equals(courseCode,otherObj.courseCode) 
                && Objects.equals(courseName, otherObj.courseName) 
                && Objects.equals(section, otherObj.section)
                && Objects.equals(group, otherObj.group);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(courseCode, courseName, section, group);
        }       
    }

    public static class Timings {
        String time;
        String day;
        String room;

        Timings(String time, String day) {
            setTime(time);
            setDay(day);
        }

        public String getTime() { return time; }
        public String getday() { return day; }

        public void setTime(String time) { this.time = time; }
        public void setDay(String day){this.day = day;}
    }
}
```

In above code I have created `Course` class to be used as the `key` for the HashMap and using a `List<Timings>` for values. What I intend is to get a List of timings when a `Course` is passed to `hm.get(course)`.  So far I can get a `keyset` then sequentially get values for each course.

```
for(Course c : timetable.tm.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(c.getCourseCode() + " " + c.getCourseName());
    for(Timings t : timetable.tm.get(c)) {
        System.out.println(t.time + " " +t.room + " "+ t.day);
    }           
};
```

Here's the code that populates the HashMap

```
static TimeTableDataModel timetable = new TimeTableDataModel();

Course course = new Course(courseCode,null,section,group);
Timings dt = new Timings(time, getDayOfWeek(i));
dt.room  = roomNo;
timetable.addNewTimeTableItem(course, dt);
```

So to get the timings for a particular course I have to traverse the whole `HashMap` until the desired `course` Key is found.  What I want is a way to distinguish between each `course` object contained in the `HashMap` Key, so I can get `Timings` for any random course without traversing the whole `KeySet`.

Thanks in advance.  Please ask if somethings is unclear in code

Comment: What does ``hm.get(course)`` return? ``null``? If so, can you post your code to test this behavior? Your code looks fine so I suspect a misuse of the map.

Comment: Can you include code that populates the data? How can we know what you expect to see as output? The code appears fine.

Comment: Please show the code which populates the time table (as James requested before) and also the code that does not behave as expected, e.g. a System.out.println(tm.get(...)); and the exact output of that code, and what you expect.

Comment: Added the requested code, so the exact output that I want would to get a list of timings by providing any course key rather than traverse the whole keyset.

Answer (score 2):

Problem what I see here is

```
 if(!tm.containsKey(course)){
        addCourseItem(course);
    }
```

and

```
if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
```

because you are comparing the object. Since both are same class objects equals will always return true and map concludes it as duplicate key.

Comment: The '==' operator is to check whether the two objects refer to the same memory location or not.